# JavaScript - Prototype Based Programming - this.myFunction is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, prototype, prototype-programming

I have instantiated the JavaScript *object* "User". It contains all the necessary for the user management. Even loading and possible AJAX error are managed here.
Below there's a snapshot of this object.

```
var User = function(uid, ajaxURL) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.ajaxURL = ajaxURL;
     };
     User.prototype = {
        loadingShow: function (tag) {
            this.tag = (tag) ? tag : '.tab-pane';
            $(this.tag + ' .loading').html('<img src="img/template/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading...">').fadeIn('fast'); 
            },
            //...
    };
    User.prototype.loadAction = function (rel) {
        var utls = new User();
            var relAttr = rel;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this.ajaxURL + '&id=' + parseInt(this.uid),
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                toDo: relAttr
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                utls.loadingShow('#' + relAttr + '-tab');
            },
            //...
```

It works fine but i have just a question, perhaps stupid but I'm facing for first times JavaScript OOP and Prototype-Based-programming.

Why must i create `var utls = new User();` for call this `utls.loadingShow(` and not simply call it by `this.loadingShow(`?
Using the `this` property i obtain the error *"TypeError: this.loadingShow is not a function"*.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the `loadAction` method, specifically the part that comes after the call to `$.ajax`?

Comment: I edited the post as you required :) Thx

Comment: You don't have to create a new one, you just need to understand scope. Inside the ajax functions thisArg is no longer pointing to the User object, but likely window or the jQuery ajax or something else. you can use Function.bind or store the thisArg outside of the ajax function scope. or I suppose according to Cooke Monster's answer there is a context property you can use :P

Comment: Great. I have already seen the "possible duplicate" but i didn't understand that i had to put the var `utls = this;` outside the AJAX call. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RobertoRizzi the more correct answer since you are using jQuery.ajax would probably to use the 'context' property when creating the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Why must i create var utls = new User(); for call this utls.loadingShow( and not simply call it by this.loadingShow(?"*

Because `this` in the callback is set to the jqXHR object.

To override it, you can set the `context:` property of the `$.ajax` request to the `this` value that you want.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.ajaxURL + '&id=' + parseInt(this.uid),
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this, // <-- set the `this` value of the callbacks
        data: {
            toDo: relAttr
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
        //   v--- now it's correct
            this.loadingShow('#' + relAttr + '-tab');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var art_tmp_str = '';

 // Why are you using this? ---v
 //           $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {

             //   v--- now it's correct
                this.loadingHide('#' + relAttr + '-tab');
                $('#' + relAttr + '-tab').html(''); 
                if(data.success === true) {
                               //   v--- now it's correct
                    art_tmp_str = this.writeAction(relAttr, data);
                    $('#' + relAttr + '-tab').append(art_tmp_str);
                } else
                    $('#' + relAttr + '-tab').append('<p>' + data.error + '</p>');
//            });
```

---

Furthermore, there shouldn't be any need to give a handler to `.ajaxComplete()` when you're already in a `success` callback. This should be done before any ajax requests are made if you really want a single behavior applied to all completed requests.

Comment: I couldn't ask anything better!
Thank you very much!! :)